# Powershell command Azure automation

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell

Need to fetch logic app primary and secondary access keys and store them in a variable in powershell cmdlet ,the requirement is to then update the key vault secret already holding the old versions of the access keys for that logic app and also is there a way to regenerate access keys with cmdlet

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to fetch the keys either through Portal or PowerShell, or CLI. If you are looking specifically to create a URL you can go with the below and this document also speaks about callback URl.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#generate-shared-access-signatures-sas